# Heroku deployment error: failed to push some refs to

Tags: reactjs, git, heroku

Front-end react based app.

I initialized a git repo to github, used git a . to add everything, git commit -m "", then git push to push everything to my repo.

Then I used heroku create to create a heroku app which worked

However, when I try to push it all to heroku app with git push heroku master I get this error: error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/todo-bja.git'

I've done this process before without any errors so am I missing something? (Using a webpack that includes Procile and everything needed.)

Comment: What is the entire output of the git error? Also, what is the git command you are using? If you don't care about any commits that may be on the heroku remote, the solution will probably be to force push.

Comment: Here is the git command I use and the full error: blakeallred@Blakes-MBP Todo % git push heroku master
error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/todo-bja.git'

Comment: Have you actually committed anything? I get `Aborting commit due to empty commit message.` when using `git commit -m ''`

Comment: Ahh, yes I found my answer in the link you provided. apparently as of October 1st 2020 github changed from using master to main so I had to change my command to the main branch instead of master. Quite confusing for people like me that weren't aware of this sudden change yet. Thank you!